# ASP MVC + AJAX, trying to Update a div asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I'm new to Asp MVC, and I'm trying to accomplish a little async update (I'm using MVC3 RC2, with Razor, but I can manage with ASPX solutions too).

I have a Master page, which renders a shopping cart box on every page by calling Html.RenderAction("Cart","Shop"). The Cart action of the ShopController calls the database, etc, and outputs the results. This works.
**First problem:** if I put an ActionLink in this partial view (like Html.ActionLink("Remove")), then even if I call PartialView() from the Remove action, it renders only the shopping cart, and nothing else (in essence, my page disappears).
**Second problem:** There is a div called "cartContent" inside this partial view. I want to be able to put a link ANYWHERE (not just on the Master page or in the partial view), which when pressed calls a controller Action, and then updates ONLY the cartContent div based on the results. I've tried Ajax.ActionLink but it does the same as Html.ActionLink, even though I imported the Microsoft.MvcAjax js libs.
Also, if I solve the first problem, I want that to be async as well.

What solution do I use? I've tried setting UpdateTargetID to "cartContent", I've tried wrapping the cartContent into an Ajax.BeginForm, nothing. Do I HAVE to use jQuery (which I know nothing of)? Do I serialize some response to JSON, and update the div manually in Javascript? (I'm not really good at JS, I'm coming from the C# side of things)

Comment: ajax.beginform should be the answer, did you enable the mvc ajax javascript in the default master layout? it is disabled by default as I remember. http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/05/19/ASPNETMVCAjaxBeginForm.aspx may help also

Comment: that's the same page I've read over and over. And I have the following lines in my _Layout.cshtml (that's like the SiteMaster's template):<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put a link wherever you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("remove item", "remove", "somecontroller", 
    new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "remove" })
```

And then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        // when the link is clicked
        // perform an ajax request:
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'delete',
            success: function(result) {
                // when the AJAX call succeed do something with the result
                // for example if the controller action returned a partial
                // then you could show this partial in some div
                $('#someDivId').html(result);
            }
        });

        // don't forget to cancel the default action by returning false
        return false;
    });
});
```

Remark: if the div you are updating contains also the link then you might need to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function or the click event handler will not work the second time because the DOM will be modified:

```
$('.remove').live('click', function() {  
     ...
});
```

Comment: type: 'delete' <- what is this? (I understand the rest, trying right now, thank you very much)

Comment: @TDaver, it indicates to use the DELETE HTTP verb. So your controller action might be decorated with `[HttpDelete]`. When deleting a resource on the server it is a good idea to use the DELETE verb. It is more RESTful.

Comment: wow! Something is working :) I'll try the live when I get back from work. One more thing: do I have to write this JS for every div I want async refreshed or can I make a general one? Why isn't there one like this in the MS AJax libraries? Thanks btw, you just made my day!